# How I Know What Classes Use Magento 2.3 with Bootstrap 3.7?

Tags: magento2, frontend

I learn in a website blog, the magento 2.3 use bootstrap 3.7, but I don't know what classes use this bootstrap edition, Any have a guide for this?

Comment: I don't believe magento uses bootstrap unless thats specific to 2.3. I'm only finding articles on how to **add** bootstrap to your Magento theme. Do you have a link to this blog post?